# authentication with mongo shard

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I am setting up a Mongo test shard and would like to use Mongo user  authentication with it.  I have added the user on the config server(s).  I am not certain if I need to add the same user on all the shards as well.  I am assuming I do not need to add the user on the query router (mongos).  However, when I simply add the user on the config server (via the Mongo shell), I can authenticate if I stay in the shell.  However, as soon as I log out of the shell and log back in, I am unable to log back in with the same credentials.  The shard servers do have a data directory associated with them as does the config server.  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this further?

**Creating user**

```
db.createUser( { user: "test",
                 pwd: "testPassword",
                 roles: [ { role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" },
                          { role: "readAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
                          "readWrite"] },
               { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 } )
```

**authenticating**

```
db.auth("test", "testPassword")
```

I did specify a data directory for the config server (running on port 27019, not 27017 & the data directory has the correct permissions for the mongo process).

```
mongod --configsvr --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb3   --port 27019
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the mongo cluster is properly setup (query router connected to config server and shards with replica sets & config serers/shards writing to disk), I was able to simply add the user via the query router and get authentication working with a Mongo Java driver